# Force vote for close reason as opposed to immediate closure due to badge privilige

Tags: feature-request, voting, review-page

Is there a way to flag a question to be voted on closure rather than immediately close the question because I have a badge privilege for a particular tag (i.e. [battery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery), [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos), etc.)

There are times when I’m absolutely certain something should be closed and then other times I’m pretty sure but would like to put it up for a vote in the review queue.

Is there a way to do this or is this a feature request for the site (SE) as a whole?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any voting functionality related to this.

One way to at least get a second pair of eyes would be to flag for mod attention instead of directly putting it on hold. With that, at least you wouldn't decide alone.

Comment: Agreed, probably the best way to go in this scenario.

Comment: I’ve seen other sites have chat rooms self organized on moderating open and close queues and candidates, but our chat is small enough asking for help there would be an alternative to getting an other flag and second look.

Comment: I’ll give both of these a go and see which one works better.  Last thing I want to do is give more work to the mods unnecessarily.

Comment: @Allan Don't worry, we'll tell you if it gets too much. A flag or two a day won't cause any undue effort.

Answer (score 2):

You could leave a comment suggesting the question is a duplicate, rather than cast an actual vote, and hope someone else (perhaps even the author) picks it up from there.

A workaround would be to edit the tags, vote to close as a duplicate, and then revert the tag edit. This does bump the question, which may be annoying if it's an old one.